# How and Where to Store Log Files in Spring Boot App deployed in CF or Heroku?

Tags: logging, heroku, spring-boot, jhipster, cloud-foundry

I have created a JHipster webapp(SpringBoot & Angular Js) and deployed it on Pivotal CF and Heroku.

I am saving the log files under the `src/main/webapp/logs/` directory which is working fine in localhost, but I am getting below error message when deployed in Pivotal CF and Heroku

> Sorry, an error has occurred.
>
> Status: Not Found (Not Found)
>
> Message: No message available

**Questions**:

1. I am able to view list of logs files and download or view the content of log file in localhost, but when deployed in CF or Heroku I am only able to see the list of log file names, but cannot access the log file.
   Since I am able to see the list of file names, that means logs files exists in CF/Heroku directory. So why am I not able to access them?
2. Can I save log files in Heroku or Pivotal CF app space?
3. I understand that I should not save log files as I did above, just wanted to know why this isn't working in CF/Heroku?
4. What is that best, easy and cheaper way to store log files when my app is deployed on Heroku or CF? AWS S3 storage?

Here is my [project repo](https://github.com/RawSanj/blogAggr).

Here is link to my app in [Heroku](https://blogaggr.herokuapp.com)

> Login with below credentials:
>
> UserName : user Password : user
>
> Navigate to Administration -> Logs
>
> Please do not change the Password. Thanks!

Below is my code snippet:

Returns the list of log file names in `src/main/webapp/logs/` directory.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logs/files",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public List<String> getLogFileNames() throws IOException {

    Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("file:src/main/webapp/logs");
    System.out.println("resource : "+ resource);
    File file = resource.getFile();
    File[] listFiles = file.listFiles();
    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
    List<File> list = Arrays.asList(listFiles);
    for (File f : list) {
        System.out.println(f.getName());
        fileNames.add(f.getName());
    }           

    return fileNames;
}
```

logback-spring.xml config:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>src/main/webapp/logs/logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <Pattern>%d %-5level [%thread] %logger{0}: %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

log.service.js:

```
angular.module('blogaggrApp')
.factory('LogsFileNameService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/logs/files', {}, {
        'getLogFileNames': { method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    });
});
```

logs.html :

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-md dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Click to Open Log Files
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in logFileNames" value="{{value}}" style="width:100%;">
            <a ng-href="/logs/{{value}}" target="_blank"><strong>{{value}}</strong> </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a cloud foundry environment, an app instance runs in a container. The container, in PCF, is a Garden cell. The storage that the cell has is called "Ephemeral Storage". That means, the app has the storage, as long as the container is alive. https://dzone.com/articles/the-12-factor-app-a-java-developers-perspective

If the app instance dies, the Cloud Foundry brain will destroy the container. This includes the ephemeral storage. When a new app instance is started, its container will have completely new storage, again ephemeral.

That is why, in Cloud Foundry, you cannot rely on local filesystem at runtime for your app.

Please take a look at the "12 Factor App" documentation (https://dzone.com/articles/the-12-factor-app-a-java-developers-perspective). It will come in handy on developing cloud-native apps.

Comment: After going through Docker concepts I realized that "If the app instance dies..." would be the case for PCF and Heroku as well. But then how do you store your logs? "12 factor apps" says to just Sysout the logs. How do I configure other tools (say Splunk or ElasticSearch) to capture logs? Any reference links?

Comment: PCF provides  `loggregator` component for accumulating logs from all components and apps from the foundation. Here is a link to the article explaining it -  http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-8/loggregator/architecture.html. 

All logs are exposed out through an endpoint called as a "firehose". To capture logs, install a "nozzle". A "nozzle" app, after deploying to cloud foundry, connects to the "firehose" and forwards logs to Splunk or Kafka bridge.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/firehose-to-syslog

Comment: The other thing you can do is install the `firehose-plugin`.  https://plugins.cloudfoundry.org/
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/firehose-plugin

It will allow you to see generated logs in a live situation and give you an idea what is a firehose.